# Best practices when deploying Dynamics CRM to Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, cloud, dynamics-crm, infrastructure

Are there any recent best practices / guidance for deploying Dynamics CRM (eg 2016) to Azure virtual machine IaaS (eg Windows Server 2016)?

In case you ask, we are pursuing this to control licensing costs.

I'm familiar with the Microsoft whitepaper from 2015, [Deploying Microsoft Dynamics CRM in Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49193), but it is somewhat dated and Azure / cloud service providers have evolved tremendously in the past 4 years.

Are there any newer best practices / guidance? Are there any gottchas?

I've looked in some depth at SQL Server 2016 on Azure virtual machines, some examples of the Azure-specific guidance there would be:

- tempdb on D: ephemeral disk ([credit Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/08/whats-different-about-sql-server-in-cloud-vms/))
- backups on [storage blogs mapped by URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-use-azure-blob-storage-service-with-sql-server-2016) ([credit Microsoft in DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246127/azure-blob-storage-container-vs-vm-managed-disk-for-sql-on-azure-vm-database-fil))
- storage spaces (pools) for enhanced performance of Azure data disks
- [several Azure Quickstart Templates for SQL Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/resources/templates/?term=%22sql%20server%22)
- etc

There is [no mention of Dynamics (CRM or otherwise on-server) in the Azure Quickstart Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/resources/templates/?term=%22dynamics%20crm%22).

I'm looking for equivalent guidance for Dynamics CRM on Azure VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not going to find any Azure Templates for CRM because Microsoft is generally trying to push everyone to use Dynamics 365 Online.  Without knowing your situation, that would always be my recommendation since you're essentially trying to create a cloud hosting solution for a product with a cloud hosting solution.

However, I understand that there are circumstances that would prevent this.

With that said, the guide seems relevant even if it's outdated.  You can still set up the VMs using the plan recommended in the guide even if the steps may change.

Also, whenever I set up on-prem hosting, I would need to set up an ADFS server.  This was always a separate VM that only ran ADFS and nothing else.  Fortunately, Microsoft Docs have a pretty reference for creating ADFS in Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/how-to-connect-fed-azure-adfs